# Homework: impedance equivalence with transformer

Tags: transformer, ac, impedance

I am working on this homework problem and I am wondering if my approach for finding Zeq is correct.

I know my matrix is correct, but I feel like I need to do something else to find the correct equivalent impedance.

Is my approach correct?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks correct, but let me solve and see if I get the same....
$${V_{1}=6V_{2}}$$
$${6I_{1}=I_{2}}$$
Assuming that voltage rises are positive and voltage falls are negative...
$${10\angle0-V_{1}-6({I_{1}-I_{2})=0}}$$
$${+6({I_{1}-I_{2})+V_{2}-(-j6)I_{2}=0}}$$\

$${10\angle0-V_{1}-6({I_{1}-6I_{1})=0}}$$
$${+6({I_{1}-6I_{1})+\frac{1}{6}V_{1}-(-j6)(6I_{1})=0}}$$\

$${10\angle0=V_{1}+6({I_{1}-6I_{1})}}$$
$${10\angle0=V_{1}-30I_{1}}$$
$${+36({I_{1}-6I_{1})+V_{1}-(-j6)(36I_{1})=0}}$$
$${-180I_{1}+V_{1}+j216I_{1}=0}$$
$$V_{1}=(180-216j)I_{1}$$
$$10\angle0=(150-216j)I_{1}$$
$$Z_{seen}=150-216j=262.98\angle-55.22\, degrees$$
Yes, it is correct.